# How do I output the differences between two columns of different lengths?

Tags: r

Lets assume that a bank creates a list of account ID's every morning, and they also wish to see the accounts that were opened/closed over the course of each day. Assuming that there are only two columns of data (with a different number of rows), how could the bank generate this report?

Day 1 IDs: 300, 301, 302, 303, 304, 305

Day 2 IDs: 302, 304, 305, 306

Comment: please read about [what a reprex is](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so it is easier for us to help you

Comment: Greetings! Your example would work better if you had a theoretical dataset people could work with to share. Usually it is helpful to provide a minimally reproducible dataset for questions here. One way of doing this is by using the `dput` function. You can find out how to use it here: https://youtu.be/3EID3P1oisg

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```r
setdiff(Day_1_IDs, Day_2_IDs)
setdiff(Day_2_IDs, Day_1_IDs)
```